# Quisiera saber por que me sale este error, net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, angular

Construí una api en php y mysql, y la subí a 000webhost, luego hice la interfaz en angular para hacer el consumo de esta api y la subí a firebase, pero cuando se realizan las peticiones get, post, put, delete me lanza este error net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR, también me lanza el error política de CORS: No hay un encabezado 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Cunado la pruebo teniendo la api en mi escritorio, en localhost, al igual que la interfaz en angular y con la extensión allow cors activa esta funciona perfectamente.

quisiera saber que barbaridades estoy cometiendo o que me falta hacer para evitar estos errores.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: El error puede deberse a que la API no tiene configurado un certificado SSL.  Eso debido a que la aplicación en firebase se sirve sobre SSL y por eso el navegador bloquea el contenido mixto.

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos, incluir (no pegar imágenes) del código que haga replicar el problema o donde creas que esté el problema, etc. El formular una buena pregunta, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: la dirección de la api es este https://apipacientes.000webhostapp.com,  asi que tambien se sirve sobre ssl

Comment: Busca [como configurar cors en php](https://www.google.com/search?q=como+configurar+cors+en+php&oq=como+configurar+cors+en+php&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30.4898j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Es un tema de seguridad en el cual tu api debe responder con una cabecera donde permita que tu gui se conecte. Al no existir dicha cabecera, el navegador, por seguridad bloquea la conexión. Esto es lo más común pero también puede ser por otras razones.

Answer (score 0):

Yo casualmente pase x lo mismo. En mi caso fue una API en Laravel y el FrontEnd en React.js. En fin tuve q montar la api en otro hosting y el front en 000webhost. El otro hosting que utilice fue alwaysdata. Saludos espero resuelvas

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).